# PHP IntlDateFormatter->format() returns false

Tags: php, date, datetime, internationalization, intl

This code works perfectly on my development server, but when I run it on another server, it fails:

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('en-GB', IntlDateFormatter::LONG, IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 'Europe/London');
var_dump($formatter->format(new DateTime('2012-06-01')));
var_dump($formatter->getErrorMessage() . ' ' . $formatter->getErrorCode());
```

Gives me:

```
bool(false) 
string(14) "U_ZERO_ERROR 0"
```

Does anyone know why? It's particularly odd that it doesn't even report an error (U_ZERO_ERROR is the default). Thanks.

**Edit:**

For comparison, locally I get:

```
string(11) "1 June 2012" 
string(14) "U_ZERO_ERROR 0"
```

I'm seeing the same issue with other locales as well, including `en-US`.

Answer (score 3):

OK, figured it out. Only PHP 5.3.4+ allows DateTime objects to be passed to format. On older versions you need to do:

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-06-01');
$formatter->format($date->getTimestamp());
```